# Where should I ask?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions on programs on C/C++, in which I am facing some problems on Loop oriented programs. :/

Comment: You'll need to add some more detail here; what *kind* of problems? Did you check the Stack Overflow [FAQ] to see if that might be a suitable site for your question? What other sites in the [Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com/sites) did you take a look at?

Comment: Programming questions belong on StackOverflow. But if your question just consists of "here's my program, it's not working," you'll have to add more detail than that

Comment: maybe the computer science section or stack overflow.

Comment: thank you @DavidRobinson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really hard to understand what you're asking, but I'll give it a shot.

If you're asking a question about programming C or C++, then Stack Overflow is the place to ask those questions.

But remember, you need to be specific in your problem. If you are vague in asking your question (hint: this question also seems vague), then it's likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: thank you @george stocker
that was certainly helpful

Comment: Do a _seroius_ effort to find (and fix) your problem before posting. Slogging through the neverending stream of "My program crashes" (Yes, it does. Don't just define a pointer and assume it is magically an array of unspecified size) soon gets tiresome.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask programming specific questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Here are few things to keep in mind:

- Read the [**faq**](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) before you post any questions.
- Read the [**about**](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page to understand how Stack Overflow works.

Your question should have the following components:

- Code snippet where you are facing the issue
- The attempts you have made to fix/resolve it
- Including searches on the web or on Stack Overflow website itself. If you found search results, mention what did not help.
- Specific area in the code snippet where you are struggling to understand what it does.
- Avoid posting long code snippets.